# Why do I get "The property 'Pages' does not have an accessible setter" for a simple <FixedDocument> in Expression Blend 4?

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend, fixeddocument

I have a XAML file which I have pared down to find the cause of this issue to the following minimal case:

```
<FixedDocument
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" >

    <PageContent>

    </PageContent>
</FixedDocument>
```

It opens fine in a KAXAML, but when I open the same file in Expression Blend 4, I get the following 2 errors at the `<PageContent>` tag:

- The property 'Pages' does not have an accessible setter
- The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: 'PageContentCollection'.

There is no CodeBehind. The only interesting thing is that this file exists in a Winforms project, and I have applied the following hack:
http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/c726522f-c721-42a7-8bf1-c73360edaa60 - but the problem also happens with the file in a straight WPF project.

Does anyone know why, and have a fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug is as old as time and it doesn't appear it will be fixed any time soon:

- [WPF FixedDocument object doesn't allow PageContent children](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/293646/wpf-fixeddocument-object-doesnt-allow-pagecontent-children)
- [WPF: FixedDocument in Visual Studio 2008 Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133240/wpf-fixeddocument-in-visual-studio-2008-designer)

Confirmed still to exist for both VS2010 and Expression Blend 4.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, none of my searches found those; perhaps the wording of this question will help others on the trail.

Comment: Unfortunately still broken in 2013 as well.

Comment: VS 2015 - still the same. A shame.

Comment: VS 2017: yep, still there. Surely this is just getting embarrassing by now.

Comment: VS 2019: Still there. Ridiculous.

Comment: VS 2022 Still there.

Comment: Today's XKCD seems relevant... https://xkcd.com/2881/ ...hello, friends :)