# Serialization of derived FixedDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, xps

Since you can only add pages to a FixedDocument, I wrote a derived class:

```
public class CustomFixedDocument : FixedDocument
{
    public void RemoveChild(object child)
    {
        base.RemoveLogicalChild(child);
    }
}
```

to replace FixedDocument, which works fine, until I try to print the document and receive the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Xps.XpsSerializationException' occurred in
>   ReachFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Serialization of this type of object is not
>   supported.

I haven't worked with serialization that much in the past and have read up on it but still can't solve the issues. I have also tried the

```
[Serializable]
```

attribute, but it doesn't make any difference.

Can anybody guide me in the correct direction or have any ideas what to do?

Comment: How exactly do you print it?

Comment: I have added a `DocumentViewer` object that binds to the `FixedDocument`: `<DocumentViewer Document="{Binding Path=DocumentView}"/>`

Comment: The `DocumentViewer` then adds all the controls needed to print. I would then just click the print button select a printer and print the document. When testing I just select a pdf printer, the error appears exactly at this point (after selecting the pdf printer and clicking print)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at decompiled source code of the method which checks if certain type is supported, you will see roughly the following:

```
internal bool IsSerializedObjectTypeSupported(object serializedObject)
{
  bool flag = false;
  Type type = serializedObject.GetType();
  if (this._isBatchMode)
  {
    if (typeof (Visual).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type != typeof (FixedPage))
      flag = true;
  }
  else if (type == typeof (FixedDocumentSequence) || type == typeof (FixedDocument) || (type == typeof (FixedPage) || typeof (Visual).IsAssignableFrom(type)) || typeof (DocumentPaginator).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    flag = true;
  return flag;
}
```

Here you see that this type should either inherit DocumentPaginator, Visual, or be exactly of type FixedDocument, FixedDocumentSequence, FixedPage. So, types inherited from FixedDocument will not work, whatever serializable attributes you will use, so you have to find a different approach. I think that is a bug in XpsSerializationManager, but maybe there is some deep reason.

Comment: That is unfortunate, thought I had the issue with removing pages from a FixedDocument solved. Anyway, back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try the OP's approach and see if I can get it to work.

According to the snippet posted by Evk, although the `IsSerializedObjectTypeSupported()` function will not accept our own custom derivative of `FixedDocument`, it will accept a `DocumentPaginator`, and one of the overloads of `XpsDocumentWriter.Write()` accepts a paginator, so that should work, right?

Well, it turns out that if you do `XpsDocumentWriter.Write( myFixedDocument.DocumentPaginator )` (where `myFixedDocument` is a custom derivative of `FixedDocument`) then something throws a `NullReferenceException` somewhere deep in library code. So, no luck there.

However, according to the same snippet, a `FixedPage` is also a supported type, and the `XpsDocumentWriter.Write()` method has another overload which accepts individual instances of `FixedPage`.

So, the following code worked for me:

```
foreach( FixedPage fixedPage in 
        fixedDocument.Pages.Select( pageContent => pageContent.Child ) )
    xpsDocumentWriter.Write( fixedPage );
```

(Where `Select()` comes from `using System.Linq`)